# Problem in Uploading Multiple Images in Flutter using http Multipart

Tags: node.js, flutter, amazon-s3, multer, multipart

I want to upload multiple Images using `http Multipart` in flutter. Below is the code I am using.

```dart
Future<void> updateUser({
    required WidgetRef ref,
    required UserModel userModel,
    required List<File?> allImages,
    required dynamic avatar,
  }) async {
    try {
      /// Call update user api
      /// If success navigate to home screen
      var response = await _httpClient.put(
        url: ApiConstants.user.getUser,
        body: userModel.toMap(),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${ref.read(authController).userToken}',
        },
      );
      log.info(ref.read(authController).userToken);
      log.fine(userModel.toMap());
      print('response.body ${response.body}');

      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'PUT',
        Uri.parse(ApiConstants.user.getUser),
      )..headers.addAll({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${ref.read(authController).userToken}',
        });
      // print('file sending path ${allImages[0]!.path}');
      log.info('allImagesPath ${allImages[0]!.path}');
      // var imagePathdata =
      //     await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('media', allImages[0]!.path);
      for (final image in allImages) {
        print(image!);
        var stream =
            image.readAsBytes().asStream(); // Use the current image variable
        var length = await image.length();

        var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
          'media',
          stream,
          length,
          filename: image.path.split('/').last,
        );
        log.info(multipartFile.filename);
        log.info(multipartFile.contentType);
        request.files.add(multipartFile);
      }

      log.info('Files:${request.files}');
      // log.info('Image Path : $imagePathdata');
      // request.files.add(imagePathdata);
      var response2 = await request.send();
      var responsed = await http.Response.fromStream(response2);
      // var responsedData = json.decode(responsed.body);
      print(
          'responsedData ${response2.statusCode} ${response2.headers} responsed: ${responsed.body}');
      if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Images uploaded successfully');
      } else {
        print('Failed to upload images. Status code: ${response2.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

But it is giving the following error.

```
I/flutter (16922): <pre>Error: Unsupported File!!<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at multerFilter (file:///home/ubuntu/Swayye-BackEnd/middlewares/multer.js:10:8)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at wrappedFileFilter (/home/ubuntu/Swayye-BackEnd/node_modules/multer/index.js:44:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Multipart.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/home/ubuntu/Swayye-BackEnd/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:107:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Multipart.emit (node:events:513:28)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.cb (/home/ubuntu/Swayye-BackEnd/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:358:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.push (/home/ubuntu/Swayye-BackEnd/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:162:20)<
I/flutter (16922): Failed to upload images. Status code: 500
```

[Error Image Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLqLP.png)

Through Multer I am trying to upload the image in the s3 bucket and storing key values of images.
I am successfull in uploading 1 image but getting above error in the sending multiple images.

Below I am providing the `multer` code in the backend.

```js
const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const supportedTypes = ["jpeg", "png"];
  if (supportedTypes.includes(file.mimetype.split("/")[1])) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Unsupported File!!"), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3Client,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
  }),
  fileFilter: multerFilter,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1, // we are allowing only 1 MB files
  },
});

export default upload;
```

Controller Code

```js
const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { value, error } = userValidator(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(403).json({ message: error.message });

  value.avatar = req?.files?.avatar?.key;
  value.media = req?.files?.media?.map((item) => item?.key);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, value, {
    new: true,
  });
  res.json(user);
};
```

Route Code

```js
 router.put(
    "/users",
    authorize,
    upload.fields([
      { name: "avatar", maxCount: 1 },
      { name: "media", maxCount: 6 },
    ]),
    updateUser
  );
```

While trying to upload files via postman it is working absolutely fine but giving error while trying to upload through Multipart in flutter.

Please provide any viable solution.

Expected Output
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdyNO.png)

In the current output I am getting an empty array list in `media` field.